# Can I run new COM("WScript.Shell") on linux servers in PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec

I tried new COM("WScript.Shell") on windows server and it runs perfectly but it is not working on Linux server, is it possible to run this on linux at all without using exec() or shell_exec()?? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `COM` class only exists on Windows.

Comment: Thanks..is there any tweak for using same in linux?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Isn't there any possibility of using wine?

Comment: @Barmar i'm trying to do a background process for my site , using which I want to load content for it

Comment: Why trying creepy windows COMs in the nice POSIX environment...

Comment: If you want to run a shell command in the background, use `exec` or `shell_exec` and put `&` at the end of the command.

Comment: @V-X Mate can you send me a link where POSIX use is explained in detail?

Comment: @Barmar I want to send more then one parameters along with my command , is this possible in exec or shell_exec???

Comment: They allow you to provide a full command line. You can send parameters just like you do when typing to the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar was right and I used both COM as well as exec for my problem.The COM class only exists on Windows